# Vector Method for a Related Rates Question

Tags: calculus, vectors, physics, kinematics

A standard related related rates question is:

> *A ladder propped aganist a wall is being moved closer. If the distance between the wall and the ladder reduces by reduces by $a$ m/s, find the rate of change in the height.*

Set up an equation using the Pythagorean Theorem, and differentiate with respect to time:
$$x^2+y^2=l^2 \implies 2x\dot{x}+2y\dot{y}=0$$

Substitute $\dot{x}=-a$ and solve for $\dot{y}$
$$2x(-a)+2y\dot{y}=0$$
$$\dot{y}=a\frac{x}{y}=a \text{ cot } \alpha $$

However, can this be solved using Vector methods. I know that
$$\vec{v}_x=(-a,0)$$
But how do I proceed from there?

Comment: You are still interested in finding $\vec v_y$ so you need $\vec v=(-a, \vec v_y)$ and the Pythagorean theorem to relate the two. You won't gain anything by using vector methods.